# How to download a file created in the server's memory to the client without saving it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, netoffice

How to download a file created in the server's memory to the client without saving it (ASP.NET)?

I've generated an Excel file on server using NetOffice. BUT now, I am not able to download it to the client. I don't want to save a copy of this file on the server.

Can we send the file object created in the memory using Streams?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you can. Just pass to Response.OutputStream of your HTTP request. Something like this should work (where yourStream is a stream from your in memory excel doc):

```
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myfile.xlsx");
    yourStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
    Response.Flush();
```

Comment: Thanks @geedubb, seems to be a solution to my problem. :)  
BUT I have a small doubt regarding "yourStream" Object. Is it an object of the MemoryStream Class?

Comment: Can we use this object as following:  
    MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
    m.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);  
  
  
I might be wrong here, because we might have to pass the bytes of the file to initialize the MemoryStream object. 
It is because using NetOffice to create Excel file, I only get the objects of ExcelApplication, WorkBook, and WorkSheet classes.  Just for your information, when I do    WorkBookObject.Visible = true;  the excel file become visible at the server.  But I dont find a way to get the bytes of workbook object so that I can pass it to the MemoryStream  & init it.

Comment: Yes, what you suggest with the memoryStream should work, however I am not familiar with NetOffice. can you update your question and share a sample of code which creates your Excel file and I will try to help further?